# voronoi diagram enclosing N points

Tags: python, scipy, geometry, voronoi

I have a 200x200 2 dimensional array of data-points corresponding to an image in the, originally stored in FITS format. Each number in the array indicates the photon count at that co-ordinate in space.

I'm trying to create a Voronoi plot for these data-points as follows--

```
  import numpy
    import matplotlib
    import scipy
    from astropy.io import fits


    #Header List
    hdulist = fits.open("ElGordo_img_0540_full.fits")


    #Converting the photon data to coordinates
    #Any non-zero photon intensity is counted only once 
    #For testing purposes


    def convert_coords(data):
        coords = []    
        for i in range(len(data)):
            for j in range(len(data[i])):
                if data[i][j] >0:
                    coords.append([j,i])

        return coords





    # print convert_coords(test)

    #Image DATA array stored in the Primary header          

    data_array = hdulist[0].data


    #converting to coordinate form
    coords_data = convert_coords(data_array)

    #Making Voronoi plot
    from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d
    vor = Voronoi(coords_data)

    #Plotting Voronoi 
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    voronoi_plot_2d(vor)
    plt.show()
```

However, this method only gives Voronoi where each box has a 'single' point. [the image looks a complete mess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhbbO.png)

In order to make sense from the plot, I need a way to enclose more than one points in my Voronoi plot (I think this is referred to as 'k-th order Voronoi). How can I implement this in Python? Any preexisting libraries/methods that I may use?

Thank you

Comment: You sure you want to use voronoi? I think the k-th order voronoi will not take the photon count in count. Some other visualisation might be better

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? What does your data mean? Why are you trying to divide it into regions? What do you want the regions to mean?

Comment: Why do you want to use a Voronoi diagram here ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a weighted voronoi diagram. It's defined as the euklidian distance minus the weight.